# Flutter: Removing card from list doesnot worked

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I have created list with cards it shows successfully now i'm trying to remove cards using delete button but doesn't remove it

code which i written

```
   List<DriverList> list = DriverList.list();
```

Button Code:

```
      FlatButton(
              child: Text("Cancel"),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    child: new AlertDialog(
                      title: new Text("Fair Bid"),
                      content: new Text("Are you sure you want to 
                      cancel?"),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                        new FlatButton(
                            child: new Text("OK"), onPressed: () {
                              list.removeAt(index);
                        }),
                      ],
                    ));
              },
```

Comment: you have to rebuild your `ListView` after deletion - read about `StatefulWidget`s

Comment: can you suggest how to do?

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/interactive#stateful-and-stateless-widgets

Comment: sure, youre welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the screen after removing the object from the List to update the ListView. One way of doing so is by calling `setState()` to redraw the Widget as demonstrated in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive#stateful-and-stateless-widgets).